# My games are showing more than 80 fps output but I can't really see that 60 fps ingame smoothness

Tags: graphics-card, performance

Actually I don't even know does this question actually belong to SuperUser, but I still wish to try. I've recently built more or less decent gaming PC with:
16 GB RAM
NVIDIA GeForce GTX-970 4Gb GDDR5 (MSI)
AMD A8 6600-K 3.9GHz (4 cores)

... and when I play for example CS:GO I can see, using ingame metrics and tools, that game is running 80 fps and more. **But I still can't see that smoothness which I see when watch, for example, 1080p 60fps youtube videos of the same game.** And it makes me kinda sad, because I built this PC with hope to play games on smooth high fps. What could be the reasons, why can't I see that smoothness? This is like game is running on 30-40 fps tops, but the game says it's 80+. The same thing with battlefield 4, it also shows 60-70fps but it is not smooth at all. Like nothing absolutely changed when I played it on 40 fps with my old configuration. I've already updated all possible nvidia drivers. Could the problem be with my monitor? It is kinda old, has 1650x1080 resolution, max 60 Hz refresh rate (which is basically the same name for 60 fps) and uses VGA port to connect to the graphics card. But it is still able to properly show youtube prerendered 60fps videos and 60 fps gifs, for example. I know what 60 fps looks like and I still can't see it in my games. **Why?**

Comment: This could be a ram problem. I had this type of thing.

Comment: Sounds like you are experiencing tearing. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is probably *timing*.
Your monitor can display one frame every ~16ms (1/60th of a second), but the GPU may produce frames in odd intervals, like two frames in the interval of one monitor frame.
This can lead to *choppiness*, ie. stuttering even though you are running more than 60fps.
From personal experience I would suggest:

1. locking the fps to a multiple of your monitor's refresh rate (60, 120, 180, 240, 300). Keep in mind that games like CS:GO need to be configured +1 because the limit will not be reached.
2. Simply enable V-sync for games that look choppy.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to optimize your graphics cards options to get exactly what you want. And that requires a lot of reading or watching youtube explanations about options and how they work and configuring them. Here are a few links which helped me a lot in the process of understanding how to configure my GPU:

- [Youtube-Link: What is Frame Rate?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zL5kOyHWI_E)
- [Youtube-Link: What is Anti-Aliasing?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hqi0114mwtY)

  - just search whatever you see in your GPU configuration options on youtube
- [What is V-Sync and when should I enable it?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/198184/what-is-v-sync-and-when-should-i-enable-it)

I would recommend start with enabling V-sync.

If your monitor is 60Hz, anything more than 60 FPS won't make *any* difference anyway, so better use it in sync with your monitor to get the desired smoothness effect for starters. Rest is about to figure out how what you want relates to certain GPU options configurations.

Answer (score 0):

I see several problems with your setup:

The CPU is very weak compared to the GPU, its not even a true quad-core and it's not even close to a Core I3.
Furthermore, every GPUs today are CPU limited even with the fastest ones.
If you consider buying a new CPU, I would recommend waiting for new AMD Zen or if you can't wait a Core I5 -which is the minimum for gaming-

The GeForce GTX 970 is known to have a problem when more than 3.5 GB of VRAM is used, on some case it happens and it's even more likely to happen in a near future.

Combining several factors -including these ones-, you may face a common problem: Stuttering.